# React parent component is re-rendering when child component changes redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working with React to create a form to edit data I am storing in my Redux Store. The data contains simple key, value pairs, in which the value is a string. It also contains key, value pairs, in which the value is an array of strings.

I've created an accordion component that allows me to render a list of inputs, one for each item. This list can be opened and closed. This item also allows for adding more items to the array that is being edited.

The issue I'm experiencing is when the array of items is updated the entire list is re-rendered which causes the user to lose focus on the input that they are typing in.

I've tried doing some checks in componentShouldUpdate() but it feels really hackey and has lead to other issues and is greatly increasing complexity.

My understanding is that React will determine what needs to be re-rendered and only re-render that single component, which in this case would be the input field that is being typed in.

You can find my code below:

```
SimpleInputList.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SimpleInput from './SimpleInput';
import { TextInput } from 'components';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
    fieldChangeAtIndex,
    fieldPush
} from '../../redux/modules/reducer';
import uuid from 'node-uuid';

import classnames from 'classnames/bind';
import css from '../../css/inputs.css';
const cx = classnames.bind(css);

@connect(state => ({
    product: state.data.product
    }), {
        fieldChangeAtIndex,
        fieldPush
    }
)
export default class SimpleInputList extends Component {

    // Hackey state stuff
    state = {
        isOpen: false,
        prevItemLength: 0
    }

    get items() {
        const { fieldName, product } = this.props;
        return product[fieldName];
    }

    get innerClasses() {
        const classes = ['inner'];
        return this.state.isOpen
            ? [...classes, 'open']
            : classes;
    }

    // Hackey state stuff
shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {

    const { fieldName, product } = this.props;
    const newItems = nextProps.product[nextProps.fieldName];
    const itemsDiff = Math.abs(this.state.prevItemLength - newItems.length);
    const isOpenChanged = this.state.isOpen !== nextState.isOpen;

    return isOpenChanged || itemsDiff;
}
 // Hackey state stuff
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isOpen: false});
}
 // Hackey state stuff
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.setState({prevItemLength: this.items.length});
}
    toggleHeader = () => {
        this.state.isOpen
            ? this.setState({ isOpen: false })
            : this.setState({ isOpen: true });
    }

    pushNew = () => {

        const {fieldPush, fieldName, label} = this.props;

        fieldPush({
            key: fieldName,
            value: `New ${label}`
        });
    }

    render() {

        const {
            label,
            fieldName,
            product,
            fieldChangeAtIndex,
            beforeDispatch,
            beforeRender
        } = this.props;

        const changeList = ListOnChange(fieldName, this.items, fieldChangeAtIndex, beforeDispatch);

        return (
           <div>
                <div className={cx('wrapper')} onClick={this.toggleHeader}>
                    <label className={cx('label')}>{label}</label>
                </div>

                <div className={cx(...this.innerClasses)}>
                    { this.items.map((item, i) => {

                        const itemVal = beforeRender
                            ? beforeRender(item)
                            : item;

                        return
                        <SimpleInput
                            key={uuid.v4()}
                            value={itemVal}
                            fieldName='_'
                            onChange={changeList(i)}
                            useDefaultValue
                        />

                    }) }
                    <a href="#ADD_{label}"
                        className="Add"
                        onClick={this.pushNew} >Add {label}</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

function ListOnChange (key, items, onChangeFunc, beforeDispatch) {
    return index => value => {
        let valueToSave = value._;
        if (beforeDispatch) {
            valueToSave = beforeDispatch(valueToSave, index);
        }
        onChangeFunc({key, value: valueToSave, index});
    }
}


SimpleInput.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'components';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
    fieldChangeAtIndex,
    fieldPush
} from '../../redux/modules/reducer';
import uuid from 'node-uuid';

import classnames from 'classnames/bind';
import css from '../../css/inputs.css';
const cx = classnames.bind(css);

export default class SimpleInput extends Component {
    render() {

        const {
            label,
            fieldName,
            value,
            useDefaultValue,
            inList,
            onChange,
            beforeDispatch
        } = this.props;

        const { setFocus, unsetFocus } = this;

        const setValue = {
            [useDefaultValue ? 'defaultValue' : 'value']: value
        };

        return (
           <div className={cx('wrapper')}>
                <label>
                { label
                    ? <span className={cx('label')}>{label}</span>
                    : null
                }
                    <TextInput
                        {...setValue}
                        onChange={simpleOnChange(fieldName, onChange, beforeDispatch)}
                    />
                </label>
           </div>
        );
    }
}

function simpleOnChange (key, onChangeFunc, beforeDispatch) {
    return val => {
        const valToSave = beforeDispatch
            ? beforeDispatch(val)
            : val;

        onChangeFunc({[key]: valToSave});
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing component state and redux state.

Comment: I am, it seems like the simplest solution to me.

Comment: The problem isn't the re-render, which is harmless. The problem is unmounting and remounting the SimpleInputs, since their uuid keys change each render. You need constant rather than random keys to avoid this. The index of the child is often a reasonable key...

Comment: @TomW Thank you! That worked!